Picklist field returning values instead of API Names in SOQL after Summer '24 release in sandbox
We have a query in similar format
SELECT COUNT(Id), toLabel(Picklist_Field__c) alias, Picklist_Field__c FROM Account WHERE Id = 'acct id' GROUP BY Picklist_Field__c ORDER BY Picklist_Field__c

The result returned in sandbox running summer '24 release is
{"expr0":1,"alias":"Hello","Picklist_Field__c":"Hello"}

instead of (this is what we see in production)
{"expr0":1,"alias":"Hello","Picklist_Field__c":"1"}

where 1 is the API Name for the 'Hello' picklist value
And it looks like this happens only when we follow the above format (using with and without toLabel on the same field and GROUP BY) meaning if we run something like below, it works fine
SELECT toLabel(Picklist_Field__c) alias, Picklist_Field__c FROM Account WHERE Id = 'acct id'

Could someone please suggest if this is what to expect after summer '24 or is it some kind of a bug? We are running into issues in our apex code due to this behavior. Appreciate any inputs!

Seems like something to raise as a support case with Salesforce.

@PhilW I'm going to raise some awareness on the issue. This is probably above support's pay grade.

More than happy for you to short-circuit the process @sfdcfox! I would still raise a case so there is a number to share with the internal folk...

Thanks for raising this up. I've reproduced it and raised it with the SOQL team to investigate the regression.

@DanielBallinger, seems to be fixed now! thanks for raising!

Thanks for raising this - will take a look into it.

Some context here. Jeremy is a Directory of Product Management at Salesforce who covers the Salesforce APIs that provide access to data on the core Salesforce Platform. He is helping with getting the bug tracked down and resolved internally.

Appreciate all the help!

@DanielBallinger, I appreciate the help of Salesforce very much! But could staff please indicate in such contributions that they belong to Salesforce? I don't investigate the affiliation of every author of a "Thank you" comment. Why should a casual reader of "will take a look into it" automatically assume he speaks as an employee of Salesforce?

@Jeremy Westerman, thank you for picking this up - I really appreciate it! Could you please add to your contribution some hint that you are an employee of Salesforce?! I made the mistake to read this as a regular, rather annoying "Thank you" answer, and I'm afraid others might too.

was this fixed? as it seems to be working as expected now! thanks a lot for taking it up!
